# UK Visa Refusal: Can I Reapply and What Should I Change? What Documents Should I Use?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

The Decision

> - you have applied for entry clearance for 10 days to visit your uncle and for tourism. In support of your application, you have submitted a letter from him inviting you, a copy of his British passport and evidence of his employment and income.
> - you have submitted a letter from your father, #####, and he states that he will be supporting you during your stay. In support of your father's circumstances you have submitted a Bank statement in his name. However, I am not satisfied that these  documents alone demonstrate your father's personal circumstances in Ghana. I am unable to determine from the documents where the Funds in his bank account originate from. As a result, I am not satisfied that the funds in this account are under his exclusive control for the purpose of your visit, nor am I satisfied that this provides an accurate reflection of his financial circumstances. I am therefore not satisfied that your father can find your visit as claimed.
> - the onus is upon you to qualify for entry clearance in your own right and I have to be satisfied as to your own circumstances . You have stated you are a student and you receive money from savings and investments and friends and family. You have submitted a bank statement in your name with your application and I note it contains some large deposits. From the documents submitted I am unable to determine the origin of these funds and as a result, I am not satisfied that your circumstances are as claimed.
> - in light of this I cannot be satisfied that your personal circumstances are as indicated in your application or that you have adequate funds available to you for the purpose of your visit. I am therefore not satisfied that you are a genuine visitor to the United Kingdom or that you intend to leave at the end of your proposed visit. Nor am I satisfied that you can be adequately maintained from funds of your own of from a third party or that you can meet the cost of your return or onward journey. 41(i)(ii)(vi)(vii)
>
> I have therefore refused your application because I am not satisfied, on the balance of probabilities, that you meet all of the requirements of the relevant paragraph of the United Kingdom immigration rules.

Can I Reapply and What Should I Change? What Documents Should I Use?

Comment: Sounds like you need to tell them about where your father works, or at least, how he makes money. Also, they want to know where you get your money from.

Comment: My father included his work details in the sponsorship letter he wrote, and I am a student and I make extra money from modeling, and organizing parties and events. How do I prove that?

Comment: Where is the question? The title doesn't count.

Comment: @JoErNanO Why not?

Comment: @Relaxed Before your edit this question was a blob of quoted text without any context. Imho it just looks like a lazy copy-paste job. Hence I don't think it qualifies as a quality question.

Comment: @JoErNanO *Quality* question I don't know. For all I care, you can also argue it's unclear or raise any number of other issues. But you seemed to imply that the text in the title was a *bona fide* question in your eyes any yet that it somehow did not count because it was not copied in the question's body. That's silly and easily remediated by editing it in.

Comment: You told us "I make extra money from modeling, and organizing parties and events.", but it doesn't look like you said that on the application.

Comment: Why the d/v? It's still a high quality question despite that it's a possible duplicate.

Comment: Saying where you get the money from isn't enough. You should provide proof of employment, and probably even some payment stubs.